# Custom circles joined with lines in UIView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I need to draw a process indicator (not a progress indicator) with dynamic changing of stroke and fill colors according to constraints. Im finding it really difficult to draw the shape that is required. Any guidance would be great.

How could i draw this? the UI should be similar to progress view but with circles in between lines. Thanks

Comment: This is such a vague question. I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish or what you have currently tried

Comment: Can you provide a set of pictures to illustrate what you're looking for?

Comment: My apologies for not being able to express in detail, the basic idea is to  dynamically draw circles connected by lines based on certain user preferences...like O-O-O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to draw this sort of thing using CAShapeLayers and QuartzCore.

Add the CoreGraphics.framework to your library.

At the top of your class

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Here is an example of something that will look like this 0-0-0 (assuming this is what you are looking for).

```
// this will be a parent layer container
CALayer *progressIndicator = [[CALayer alloc] init];

// the first bubble
CAShapeLayer *bubble1 = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
bubble1.fillColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
bubble1.strokeColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
bubble1.strokeWidth = 1;
bubble1.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,50,50)].CGPath;
[progressIndicator addSublayer:bubble1];

// the first connecting line
CAShapeLayer *line1 = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
line1.strokeColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
line1.strokeWidth = 2;

UIBezierPath *linePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[linePath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(50, 25)];
[linePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(75, 25)];

line1.path = linePath.CGPath;
[progressIndicator addSublayer:line1];

// ... And so on for the next 2 bubbles and 1 line. ...//

// Add it to your view.
[self.view.layer addSublayer:progressIndicator];
```

You can animated most properties on these objects as well (like opacity) to give your progress bar the affect of slowly filling over time.

Comment: you my friend are a life savour! exactly the way you described, i tried to upload the picture but as I'm new to the community i need to have a reputation to add picture. Will try this out